# Unexpected "Spread types may only be created from object types" error when using generics

Tags: object, typescript, interface, partial

I've got this typescript class that requires a generic type to be provided on construction:

```
type Partial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};

class Foo<Bar> {
  bis: Partial<Bar> = {}; // (1)
  constructor() {
    console.log(typeof this.bis);  // object
    this.bis = {...this.bis};  // (2) Spread types may only be created from object types
  }
}
```

How ever, as you can see above, i don't get an error at *(1)*, but i do at *(2)*. 
Why is this? And how do i fix it?

**Edit1:** 
I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17368) over at the Typescript github.

Comment: Seems like limitation on current version of TS. I would suggest you to open an issue directly at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: No need to create a new issue; I think this will be [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727) as of TS v2.5

Comment: @jcalz, not fixed yet :(

Comment: Yes, it seems that it got moved 2.5 to 2.6, to 2.7... to 2.8... to "Future".  Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this is typecasting the object explicitely with `<object>`,`<any>` or `<Bar>` in your case.

I don't know if your requirements allow this or not but have a look -

```
type Partial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
class Foo<Bar> {
  bis: Partial<Bar> = {}; // (1)
  constructor() {
    console.log(typeof this.bis);  // object
    this.bis = {...<Bar>this.bis};  
  }
}
```